# Using results of one stored procedure in another stored procedure - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Is there any way to use the results of one stored procedure in another stored procedure without using a table variable or temp table? The logic is as follows:

```
   IF (@example = 1)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE #temp TABLE (Id INT);
        INSERT INTO #temp
            EXEC [Procedure1] @ItemId = @StockId

        set @Cost = (select top 1 id from #temp)
```

Ideally i would like to know if there is a way to do this without having to use a temp table. Looked around online but can't find anything that works. Any advice would be great.

Comment: Why the aversion to using a temp table?

Comment: @MysticHeroes just wondering logically if there is anyway to do it to avoid using a table

Comment: [Background material](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html). This looks like a textbook case where a single output parameter would suffice, assuming you only ever get back one `Id`. Note that it is possible to retrofit the existing procedure with such a parameter while making it optional, so existing callers aren't required to pass it. (Just writing a new procedure is also an option, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you want to use user-defined code in a `SELECT`, then it is better to phrase the code as a user-defined *function* rather than a user-defined *procedure*.

That is, procedures should be used for their side effects and functions should be used for their return values.

That said, you can use `openquery` (documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)) to run an `exec` on a linked server.  The linked server can be the server you are running on.